# Rank and unrank permutation with special properties

Tags: arrays, algorithm, combinations, permutation, ranking

I want to `rank and unrank` permutations with special properties. How can i do this? The `both` properties of permutations in the set are:

1. each permutation has `only 1 cycle`
2. each permutation consist of subsets of permutation elements, where the subsets are in some special ordering.

For example:

The permutations with `length 6 (N := 6)` has following permutation elements: `(1,2,3,4,5,6)` with subsets:

Subset `S1 := (5,6)`

Subset `S2 := (3,4)`

Subset `S3 := (1,2)`

Where the elements are `S1 > S2 > S3`.

So the permutation has following Subset ordering: `L := (S3,S2,S1,S3,S2,S1)`

With the 1 cycle constraint, there exist just 3 permutations which fullfill `both` constraints.

`(5,3,1,6,4,2)`
`(5,4,2,6,3,1)`
`(6,4,1,5,3,2)`

Counter example:

`(6,4,2,5,3,1)` matches second constraint but not the first.

How can i rank and unrank the permutations which fullfill `both` constraints.

When I have as input parameters:

`N` as permutation length

`K` as count of subsets

`L` as list of subsets(`Si`) consisting permutation elements, where `L` defines the ordering of the subsets(`Si`).

And as output parameter the Rank or the permutation if the Rank is given?

Iam able to rank and unrank permutations with only the one constraint but not with `both` constraints. Thus the permutations will have a length bigger than 100 (`N > 100`) It will `not work` to generate all permutations of one constraint and check against the other, to get the valid permutations to rank/unrank.

Comment: Why not also (6,4,2,5,3,1)?

Comment: Because (6,4,2,5,3,1) fullfills not the first constraint, I only want to rank/unrank permutations which fullfill both constraints. This permutation has 2 cycles (6,1) and (4,2,5,3).