# Save permutation with less bytes than permutation length

Tags: arrays, algorithm, compression, permutation, ranking

I want to save a permutation of the length `N` in less than `N` Bytes. The permutation of length `N` has the elements `1,2,3,....,N`.

The permutation has following preferences:

- has only 1 Cycle
- can be described via DI sequence and a rank 
  [permutation ranking with DI sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56551442/permutation-ranking-with-di-sequence)
- has a strength 
  [Next permutation/ranking with specific strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56549685/next-permutation-ranking-with-specific-strength)

Additional reading: [Rank and unrank permutation with special properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56514684/rank-and-unrank-permutation-with-special-properties)

Is there a way to combine these preferences to minimize the possible permutations to rank?  Or are there more preferences which can be used to describe the permutation in less Bytes than it is long?

My idea was to specify a subset of permutations and then Rank it, but iam failing to combine the preferences to create one subset defined through the preferences.

Comment: For a start, you could save it in (n-1) bytes. You could store the first n-1 elements. The last one is implied

Comment: The problem description is a little vague. It could be improved by adding a detailed description to each of the bullet items. An example would also help.

Comment: @AbhayAravinda and the second to last one has only 2 possibilities and could be stored in 1 bit, etc, eventually the whole permutation can be encoded using its index in the factoradic number system. That doesn't use the special properties though.

Comment: What is a DI sequence? What is strength?

Comment: Updated description

Comment: `log(n!)≈n log(n)`, which means to store every permutation uniquely you need roughly  `n log(n)` bits. Using something like Lehmer's code you can reduce the size a bit, maybe by a factor of 2, but unless you're assuming a `Byte` is as large as `log(n)` bits you can't do better than `n log(n)` asymptotically. 
take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_code

Answer (score 1):

In general, no.

Permutations of length `n` with only one cycle are in 1-1 correspondence with permutations of length `n-1`.

The strength is a positive integer between  that cannot exceed `n^2`.

The number of possible bitstrings is `2^(n-1)`.

By the pigeon principle, for some bitstring and some strength there must be at least `(n-1)! / (2^(n-1) n^2) = n! / (2^(n-1) n^3)`.

From [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) we can see that

```
log2( n! / (2^(n-1) n^3) )
    = n log2(n) - n log2(e) + O(log2(n)) - (n-1) - 3 log2(n)
    = n log2(n) - n (log2(e) + 1) - O(log2(n))
    = n log2(n) + O(n)
```

Which tells us that the number of bits needed, even with your conditions, grows faster than linear.  So for large enough `n`, you will need more than `n` bytes of data to specify a single permutation.

Comment: Ok lets limit `n` to: 500 <= n <= 5000.

Comment: @TThoEinthausend I would bet money that it is still not possible for 5000.  The worst case scenario should be the bitstring `101010...101` and strength something like 12.5 million.

Comment: Yeah but if i have a bitstring like `...00000100000...` the defined  subset is much smaller. Usually the permutations i want to describe have a subset which can be saved in max `n*0.98` Bytes, the factor i wanna bring down with additional constraints. But combining constraints are hard.